# Spark Java use math operations to get value proportion with max cutoff

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm understanding Spark pretty well conceptually but I'm still navigating the specific syntax options for expressions. I'm using Spark 3.3.0 with Java 17.

I have a table with a column `foo` that shouldn't have values much higher than 30. I want to add a column with the proportion of `foo` with `30`, that is, the value of `foo` normalized to `0.0 <= proportion <= 1.0` with a cutoff of `30` for `foo`. Finally `foo` is a decimal type, represented in Java by `BigDecimal`.

I might make this calculation like this in Java:

```java
BigDecimal maxVal = new BigDecimal(30); 
BigDecimal proportion = foo.max(maxVal).divide(maxVal);
```

(Or I could first divide by `maxVal` and take the max of the result and `1.0`, although the first approach above is probably more efficient and more direct semantically.)

How would I best do this in Spark? The following seems to work and gets me most of the way there:

```java
BigDecimal maxVal = new BigDecimal(30);
df = df.withColumn("proportion", col("foo").divide(maxVal));
```

But what about the `max()` part so that I can cut off the value at `30`? The only "max" function I could find offhand was the Spark SQL `MAX()` aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [min](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#min-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) and [max](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#max-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) are aggregation functions that work on a group of rows, the functions [least](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#least-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) and [greatest](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#greatest-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) can compare values within a row or with a constant value.

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Dataset<Row> df = ...
BigDecimal maxVal=new BigDecimal(30);
df.withColumn("proportion", greatest(col("value"), lit(maxVal)).divide(maxVal)).show();
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+
|value|proportion|
+-----+----------+
|    1|  1.000000|
|   10|  1.000000|
|   20|  1.000000|
|   30|  1.000000|
|   31|  1.033333|
|   40|  1.333333|
+-----+----------+
```

If the values should be capped at `maxValue` one would use `least` instead of `greatest` (this would correspond to using [BigDecimal.min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#min(java.math.BigDecimal)) in the non-Spark code):

```java
df.withColumn("proportion", least(col("value"), lit(maxVal)).divide(maxVal)).show();
```

Output now:

```
+-----+----------+
|value|proportion|
+-----+----------+
|    1|  0.033333|
|   10|  0.333333|
|   20|  0.666667|
|   30|  1.000000|
|   31|  1.000000|
|   40|  1.000000|
+-----+----------+
```

Comment: Oh, perfect! It's all about knowing what name to look for. Thanks.